# with_nested doesn't work as expected to loop in array

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to create a new Ansible playbook which manage somes applicatives services.

**The idea of my playbook is :**

- Find services to manage.
- Add theses services to an array.
- To Loop over this array to stop and start my differents services.

**I did this playbook :**

```
- hosts: MyHost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    Services: []
  tasks:
  - name: "Search for service to manage"
    find:
      path: "/data/mgwroot/applications"
      file_type: directory
      patterns: '*{{ ELD }}*'
    register: FoundServices

  - name: "Add found services to array"
    no_log: true
    set_fact:
      Services: "{{ Services + [item.path | basename] }}"
    with_items: "{{ FoundServices.files }}"

  - name: "Display array content"
    debug:
      msg: "{{ Services }}"

  - name: "- TASK A -"
    shell: "echo {{ item.0 }} {{ item.1 }}"
    with_nested:
    - [ 'stop', 'start' ]
    - [ "{{ Services }}" ]

  - name: "- TASK B -"
    shell: "echo {{ item.0 }} and {{ item.1 }}"
    with_nested:
      - ['stop', 'start']
      - ['serviceA', 'serviceB']
```

And the result doesn't work as expected :-( :

- " - TASK B -", which loop from static list works correctly, but
- " - TASK A -", which loop over my dynamics array doesn't works.

**This is the result :**

```
PLAY [MyHost] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Search for service to manage] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 19 November 2020  13:25:46 +0100 (0:00:00.109)       0:00:00.109 *****
ok: [MyHost]

TASK [Add found service to array] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 19 November 2020  13:25:48 +0100 (0:00:01.260)       0:00:01.370 *****
ok: [MyHost] => (item=None)
ok: [MyHost] => (item=None)
ok: [MyHost]

TASK [Display array content] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 19 November 2020  13:25:48 +0100 (0:00:00.058)       0:00:01.429 *****
ok: [MyHost] => {
    "msg": [
        "PREPRO_MVZV14_batch",
        "PREPRO_MVZV14_tp"
    ]
}

TASK [- TASK A -] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 19 November 2020  13:25:48 +0100 (0:00:00.038)       0:00:01.467 *****
changed: [MyHost] => (item=[u'stop', u'PREPRO_MVZV14_batch', u'PREPRO_MVZV14_tp'])
changed: [MyHost] => (item=[u'start', u'PREPRO_MVZV14_batch', u'PREPRO_MVZV14_tp'])

TASK [- TASK B -] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 19 November 2020  13:25:49 +0100 (0:00:01.116)       0:00:02.583 *****
changed: [MyHost] => (item=[u'stop', u'serviceA'])
changed: [MyHost] => (item=[u'stop', u'serviceB'])
changed: [MyHost] => (item=[u'start', u'serviceA'])
changed: [MyHost] => (item=[u'start', u'serviceB'])
```

**Expected result :**

- stop PREPRO_MVZV14_batch
- start PREPRO_MVZV14_batch
- stop PREPRO_MVZV14_tp
- start PREPRO_MVZV14_tp

Does someone can explains me what i'm doing wrong ?

Thanks for all !

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,

Replace
- [ "{{ Services }}" ]
to
- "{{ Services }}"

..

:)